# Stop a Windows service and wait for it to stop by itself as opposed to get it killed by Windoes after +-15sec

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, timeout

I'm new here and have been reading a lot of questions but it's actually the first time that I have posted a question.

I'm trying to get a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to stop some services twice per day. Here is the content of my batch file:

```
net Stop "PrimusActivityLauncher"
net Stop "PrimusDesigntimeServiceHost (Designer)"
net Stop "PrimusDesigntimeServiceHost (SystemMonitor)"
net Stop "PrimusRuntimeServiceHost (Authentication)"
net Stop "PrimusRuntimeServiceHost (Configuration)"
net Stop "PrimusRuntimeServiceHost (Document)"
net Stop "PrimusRuntimeServiceHost (Process)"
net Stop "PrimusRuntimeServiceHost (SystemMonitor)"


net Stop "MSSQLSERVER"
net Start "MSSQLSERVER"
net Start "PrimusActivityLauncher"
net Start "PrimusDesigntimeServiceHost (Designer)"
net Start "PrimusDesigntimeServiceHost (SystemMonitor)"
net Start "PrimusRuntimeServiceHost (Authentication)"
net Start "PrimusRuntimeServiceHost (Configuration)"
net Start "PrimusRuntimeServiceHost (Document)"
net Start "PrimusRuntimeServiceHost (Process)"

iisreset /start
```

The problem here is that when I try to stop the first service, (`Activity Launcher`), it times out before my platform has the time to finish processing documents. I need to find a way for my batch file to wait until the documents finish processing in order to actually stop the service as opposed to kill the service. I tried to change the value of the timeout in regedit but the change has not been taken into consideration after rebooting the server. I'd find a way to specify window to wait at least 10-15 miutes before actually killing the service once it times out.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What version windows? 32 or 64-bit? What process is processing documents? Why do you say you want to stop services but your batch file stops and starts services?  Why do you say your first service is `activity launcher` but your batch file says `primusactivitylauncher`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running a looping check until the below syntax returns 0:

```
wmic service list brief | find "Stopped" | find "PrimusActivityLauncher"
```

It will only return a 0 once PrimusActivityLauncher is stopped, and will wait forever until that happens. You can code in a counter or other form of timeout if you want to stick to your plus/minus 15 seconds. Doctor this for any service name as you need, such as MSSQLSERVER/Primus*/Etc.